# How to use javascript to check if class that starts with (classname__) exists?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, I'm using the `contains()` method to check if a class that starts with `banner__` exists in the document. If I define the class explicitly, then I can get a true response. But there are various classes that could exist in the document that start with `banner__`.

**How do I check if a class that starts with `banner__` exists?**

```js
const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');
const isBanner = banner.classList.contains('banner__');
if (isBanner) {
  console.log('Exists')
} else {
  console.log('Does not exist')
}
```

```html
<div class="banner banner__holiday">Banner</div>
```

Comment: use `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: @CertainPerformance That won't work because it's the second class in the attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the class list to an array, then use `.some()` to test if any of them begin with what you want.

```js
const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');
const isBanner = Array.from(banner.classList).some(c => c.startsWith('banner__'));
if (isBanner) {
  console.log('Exists')
} else {
  console.log('Does not exist')
}
```

```html
<div class="banner banner__holiday">Banner</div>
```

Comment: That's neat. I've never seen the `some()` function. Thanks.